# Open modals with html tag <dialog>

Tags: javascript

First of all, I'm an absolutely noob with JavaScript and trying to learn this, so pls don't roast me for my question.

My Question:
I have 3  tags on my website and want to open and close the dialogs to set an 'open' attribute.
Unfortunately, I'm only able to open only 1 (the first) of the 3 modals.

```html
<!-- MODAL 1 -->
<button class="button open-button">
    click here
</button>

<dialog class="modal">
    <h4 class="modal__title">Modal 1</h4>
    <button class="button close-button">X</button>
</dialog>

<!-- MODAL 2 -->
<button class="button open-button">
    click here
</button>

<dialog class="modal">
    <h4 class="modal__title">Modal 2</h4>
    <button class="button close-button">X</button>
</dialog>

<!-- MODAL 3 -->
<button class="button open-button">
    click here
</button>

<dialog class="modal">
    <h4 class="modal__title">Modal 3</h4>
    <button class="button close-button">X</button>
</dialog>
```

And that's my js currently:

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const openModal = document.querySelectorAll(".open-button");
const closeModal = document.querySelector(".close-button");

openModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.showModal();
});

closeModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.close();
});
```

I'm not sure, how to tell js to be able to open multiple modals, when I click on the button.

Comment: `const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");` This only selects your first modal. You need to use `const modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");` to select all of your modals and then make sure the correct one is being opened. Right now you only attach your event listener to the first modal. Not the other ones. It would probably be easier to use `onclick="someFunction(modalID)"` on your buttons instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Could you pls create a complete code, I've tried it with onclick, but something went wrong. Much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Gather each `class` in a NodeList.

Bind the click event to each `button.open`. When a `button.open` is clicked, open the `dialog.modal` corresponding to it's index.

Bind the click event to each `button.close`. When a `button.close` is clicked, close the `dialog.modal` that the `button.close` reside within.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Collect each class into a NodeList
const modal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
const open = document.querySelectorAll(".open");
const close = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

/*
Bind the click event to each button.open
open the dialog.modal that corresponds to current index (idx)
*/
open.forEach((btn, idx) => btn.addEventListener("click", e => modal[idx].showModal()));

/*
Bind the click event to each button.close
close the dialog.modal that is the ancestor of the clicked button.close
*/
close.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", e => btn.closest('.modal').close()));
```

```css
dialog,
fieldset {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <button class="open" type='button'>Open 1</button>
  <button class="open" type='button'>Open 2</button>
  <button class="open" type='button'>Open 3</button>
</menu>

<dialog class="modal">
  <header>
    <h4>Modal 1</h4><button class="close" type='button'>X</button>
  </header>
  <fieldset>
    <p>Oh no. I'm late to class, bitch. </p>
    <p>Earth's going tah tah. You might wanna do that thing where you find a new universe where you can suck yourself off. </p>
    <p>God, Grandpa, you're such a dick. </p>
  </fieldset>
  <footer>
    <button class='close' type='button'>Cancel</button>
  </footer>
</dialog>

<dialog class="modal">
  <header>
    <h4>Modal 2</h4><button class="close" type='button'>X</button>
  </header>
  <fieldset>
    <p>Then let me GET to know you!</p>
    <p>I'm the Devil, what should I do when I fail? Give myself an ice cream?</p>
    <p>If I've learned one thing, it's that before you get anywhere in life, you gotta stop listening to yourself.</p>
  </fieldset>
  <footer>
    <button class='close' type='button'>Close</button>
  </footer>
</dialog>

<dialog class="modal">
  <header>
    <h4>Modal 3</h4><button class="close" type='button'>X</button>
  </header>
  <fieldset>
    <p>Oh god, oh, I blame myself. Oh, what a tragedy. Oh, well, he's bones now. I guess all debts are paid. </p>
    <p>No! Look away! I'm making an egg, Mom! Ugh…! I'm making an egg! </p>
    <p>If you break the rules, try to leave or lose the game, you will die. Just like Saaaaw.</p>
  </fieldset>
  <footer>
    <button class='close' type='button'>Close</button>
  </footer>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Rather than relying on positional indexes to open the modals, I'd be more inclined to give the dialogs IDs and use `data-target="#dialog-id"` in the buttons

Comment: That'd most certainly work, but what's even better is event delegation.

Comment: One doesn't exclude the other 